# Portable Class Library and Windows Mobile 5, 6, 6.5

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5, windows-mobile-6

Does anyone knows if the current portable class libraries are compatible with windows mobile 5, 6 or 6.5? I need to design a library to support old mobile systems as well as windows phone or android and can't figure it out if it is possible to use PCL for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, it is not possible to target both Windows Mobile and Windows Phone, since the frameworks are not compatible.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your reply. But for instance, using PCL for Windows Mobile and Android, is it doable?

If not, do you have any suggestions for this type of cross-development?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will have to make 2 separate projects I'm afraid, since Xamarin uses .NET Framework and Windows Mobile uses .NET Compact. See this list: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172550(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: It is a time anachronism, humans-and-dinosaur-movie style.  VS2008 does not support PCL and PCL does not support for .NET CF targets.  This was added after Apple killed it dead.